# Adobe Media Encoder CC - No output sound

Tags: after-effects, adobe

After I finish my project in Adobe After Effects I export the project to Adobe Media Encoder.

I choose the default setting Youtube HD 1080p 29.97. After render all the video I get no sound on the video.

Any help?

Comment: I am having the same problem... how did you resolve this? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Often by default the Audio Output checkbox is not checked in After Effects.  When you go to add the composition to the render queue, make sure Audio Output is checked.

Comment: Well, I don't add it to the After Effects queue. I add it to the Media Encoder queue. Is there any problem mixing video parts with different fps rates?

Comment: @NunoBatalha - there is no problem with different FPS rates that should cause there to be no audio.  There are issues that it will result in frame interpolation which may result in artifacts and minor audio sync issues, however it shouldn't result in no audio.

Comment: @AJHanderson - I've solved the problem. But didn't really guess why I had no sound... The only thing that I changed was some parts of video that were over other parts.